# servicestack app host vs iis for high performance REST service

Tags: servicestack

as servicestack leave it open to host service in web server or in stand alone app.

What is the best in term of performance both raw and for a high number of clients ?

Hosting on apache or nginx or XSP or IIS  is just for added functionality or for perf ?

Answer (score 2):

[servicestack.net](http://www.servicestack.net/) itself runs on Ubuntu / Nginx + MonoFastCGI, although we've been notified others have been able to get better performance with [self-hosting](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Self-hosting) which you can still serve behind a Nginx/Apache reverse proxy if you still wanted access to a full-featured web server.

You can also wrap a [self-hosted ServiceStack in a Linux Daemon](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Run-ServiceStack-as-a-daemon-on-Linux).

Comment: ok , as i understand , if i don't need web server functionality , it should be better in self-hosting ?

Comment: If by better you mean faster, yeah :)

Answer (score 2):

We've ran into same question while were choosing hosting schema for our ServiceStack services.   Ran some benchmarks with same service hosted on self-host and under IIS. SelfHost windows service has shown near 1.5x better performance than IIS-hosted app.
Surely this is not and absolute number and it may vary by service's load type (cpu/io), but it is clear, that IIS routine adds tonns of overhead.

If you need speed and don't worry about all those features IIS can give you (monitoring / advanced routing / admin / etc)- self host is the way to go. Our set-up hides ServiceStack hosts behind nginx nodes that serve all the routing/proxy/balancing stuff so we don`t need monstrous IIS-routine.